# FFMPEG conversion creates a smaller files despite unchanged codecs

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, aac

I have a h264/aac video mp4 file that FFMPEG says this about:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2015-10-15 16:41:52
  Duration: 00:03:36.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4298 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-15 16:41:53
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 4160 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-10-15 16:41:53
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
```

Then, I run a conversion on it while keeping it the same codecs and resolution with this command line:

```
ffmpeg -i x.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec libvo_aacenc y.mp4
```

The resulting output file info is:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
  Duration: 00:03:36.29, start: 0.033333, bitrate: 1913 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1780 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

It seems that the input and output file should be identical but the input file is 116MB and the resulting output file is 51.7MB.

If the codecs and resolution are the same and there is not change in the video quality for the naked eye, why is the file size is so different?

Comment: What's the reason you are doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how [lossy codecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) work.  Encoding is a tradeoff between CPU time spent on encoding, bitrate, and perceptual quality.  With different settings for the same codec, you will get different output.

Even using the exact same settings, feeding the output of x264 back in as input will cause [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) every time.  Some codecs (like prores I think) are designed so generation-loss stops after a generation or two, but h.264 isn't like that.  Partly because it has a deblocking filter in the loop, and partly just because of how it has limited accuracy for references.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 may help some, but you're misunderstanding some very basic concepts in [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).

Answer (score 0):

In given command only codec names are specified, there are additional parameters which control the quality of video while encoding.
For example, you could have given -b:v 4160 or -crf 20, then you won't see much change in the video quality and size.
If you don't specify all the parameters, ffmpeg will take the default values for them. 
If you wish to keep the same file size, you should not re-encode the video. You can use command as

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

For the referance please check this page https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264?